# Can good and evil live in harmony?

Tags: ethics, vipassana, reality

Presently I found an old steel bangle belonging to the sheik faith ...and I started to think of circle and unity how pleasent it would be to flow freely, and then I had the ephifany that this is possible except for the friction caused by opposites that have put a stop to  my flow.

Is it me or are we as yet not free from this cosmic and earthly struggle between contradictions ie good and evil //heat //cool ..night //day there seems to be a checker board pattern emerging to me . the  sessation of suffering according to my knowledge of Buddhism is to recognise the hindrances.

And rectify them in order to escape from the karma wheel of cause and effect .  so again .. Conflict if opposing ideas or suggestions would be suffering to me as well as all sentient beings in this case I'm yet again asking like many before me can there exist harmony amongst chaos ? Or good amongst evil both subjectively and objectively ....good - a small Daisy flower evil - this very flower will kill a person allergic to it!!

Comment: I'm closing this question as both question title and content is unclear. Question can be reopened once rephrased in a clearer way. Please add relevant context to the question that reflects question title. Also specify what is meant by *"good and evil"* and *"harmony"*. Also, you might consider adding the *"ethics-tag"* to your question.

Comment: Lanka you have appeared from the tear drop island and are causing a lot of pain ...it's a fair question

Comment: Edit: added line-spacing to increase readability. I still think *question-content* is unclear. We will give it a try and see what the community decides. Question reopened.

Comment: Ok good show ol chap!! Here's a very important question for you Lanka ..is your mind as you would know it belong to you or the great Lord Buddha? Very best in your responce...

Answer (score 1):

(this is less Buddhism than a demonstration that actions within the empirical world do not suit Essential concepts like 'good' and 'evil'.. though to me this flows from the Buddha's analysis!)

Moral system 1: Killing = Evil (100%).

You wake up and find yourself faced with two option (you are placed in this position by a third actor).

Option A, kill 1 person.

Option B, 100 people are killed (by that third actor).

Knowing that 'Killing = Evil', you choose option B (within that 100%, the non-relational, there can be no justification for choosing A).. In that you do not personally pull the trigger, you are not the 'efficient cause'. You have done no wrong (within your moral system).

Moral system 2: No killing > less killing > more killing.

Logically, B is never reasonable.

An essential moral construct like 'good' or 'evil' will agree with a relational moral construct in all scenarios, other than the one where it is compared to itself. As such, it is simply inefficient. No need for opposites in their essential form!

"Treat this as this, not this as that or that as this" As the Buddha said. (in other words, not 'This=This'.. given evidence from empirical experience, the law of identity is flawed!)

Now how this fits in within the Buddhist world view, whether you can put it down to past karma for finding yourself in such a position.. how to square that you are damned either way is the more interesting question! :D

Answer (score 0):

In buddhism you perceive everyhit experience in 2 opposites may it be hot or cold, long or short, good or evil, etc. as simply:

- favorable or
- unfavorable or
- do not care

If you perceive something favorable you get a good feeling about it and get attached and if unfavorable you get a bad feeling about it and get averse.

What ever experience you should keep a balanced mind and use each experience to eradicate the unwholesome roots. See: [Pahāna Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/31.1-Pahana-S-s36.3-piya.pdf). The bipolar evaluation something as favorable and unfavorable always result in either craving or aversion hence result in misery. Also may result in Sensory Desire and Ill Will.

Moreover, if you are allergic to a flower and if hurts someone, this being good or bad is matter of perception hence resulting is pleasant and unpleasant sensation followed by craving and aversion followed by becoming. So if might be that the perception which may create more misery now and in the future than a person who is getting an allergic reaction. The allergic reaction maybe his Karma or negligence. When you harmonise your mind the notion of good (being favorable) and evil (unfavorable) will not be present but you will be equanimous.

Comment: Conditioned responce is what I think you referring too... My question however is between good and evil is there an underlying factor that is inhibiting harmony...ie we all need to be happy then deciding so and applying methods like Buddhism should work

Comment: There is no good and evil per say. It is just a perception. What comes close is skillful and unskillful.